# Finding window in VS2017 using information from Spy++

Tags: winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2017, spy++

I have identified a problematic window in `Spy++`. `Spy++` gives some information about the `WinForms window`. Unfortunately, the title is blank, but there is also a window handle, and instance handle, and some other information.

The program is run from VS2017 attached to the debugger. How can I use the information given by `Spy++` to find the object in `VS2017`?

Comment: The handle is (in a way) the object. You've already found it. What do you want to do with it? Do you mean, you want to find the handle of this Window at run-time, without the help of Spy++? Also, what do you mean when you say: *find the object in VS2017*? Does this Window belong to the Visual Studio IDE itself?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, I'm running the program with the VS debugger attached. Ideally I'd like to pull up the properties of the object to help me track down where it's being instantiated.

Comment: I think you can try to use the `Find Window` and see [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-finder-tool?view=vs-2019),[two](https://electronic-design.net/visual-cpp-cli-dot-net/spy-tool/using-the-spy-tool).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Finding the handle is no problem, but what I want to do is look at the information about the window in VS

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Could you please explain the problem? What's the question exactly and What's the expected answer?

Comment: @RezaAghaei The problem is finding a specific window on a specific thread in VS2017 for a program running with the VS debugger attached. A partial solution is to identify the window with Spy++ and get the window handle, but then how can I use that to find the in memory object in VS. An expected answer is something like "break the debugger, open the X window and you can see a list of controls, then you can scroll down till you find window matching the handle you got from spy++. You can click it to inspect/watch the object" or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. l think the possible solution is that you should locate the window from spy++ and then, based on this, look for the corresponding window in vs debug.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT How can I look for that window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reputation is low so post an answer here, also cannot post images:(.

Theoretically you should see the caption in the [Windows View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/windows-view?view=vs-2019). Then you can use this variable name in your VS watch window.

If you cannot see the caption or it's empty, you can also use the handle to get the control using [Control.FromHandle(IntPtr) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle?view=netframework-4.8). For example, I have a button control with handle *0000000000040E4A*, I can get the control via *Control.FromHandle(new IntPtr(0x40E4A))* in the watch window.

[image: 3]

Best Regards,

Charles

Comment: Thank you Charles! I believe this is the correct solution, I will give it a try tomorrow. Thank you for posting this, this was not an easy question as you can see!

Comment: I've got the same problem but using C++ and MFC. @charles do you know which function to use on the place of Control.FromHandle() in C++?

Comment: @ViktorBe not familiar with MFC, have you tried GetDlgCtrlID function to get control's id?